# Memcached Integration with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, memcached, amazon-elasticache

So everybody seems to be using `hibernate-memcached` implementation (https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-memcached/wiki) for Hibernate as a second layer Memcached cache.

I tried integrating it with Hibernate, but I'm finding it's very outdated.  For example, it relies on old versions of `org.slfj` and `org.hibernate` binaries (which breaks my web service since I use newer binaries).  But even excluding those binaries at build time with Maven, it seems to be missing required setting implementations for `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` that probably got introduced with new caching policies for Hibernate.

In short, I'm running into the above error:

`org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).`

My guess is I need to write my own implementation?  I just don't know how many more broken steps there still are.

Answer (score 1):

I know what this post is old, but i think, it should be answered anyway.

Unfortunately, current hibernate-memcached version 1.4-SNAPSHOT supports only hibernate max version 3.6.6 
If you want to use is with Hibernate 4, you should fork it on github and modify it by youself.

The latest hibernate-memcached version is available at https://github.com/raykrueger/hibernate-memcached

And if you use maven, here is the snippets for you pom.xml

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>hibernate-memcached</id>
    <name>hibernate-memcached</name>
    <url>http://raykrueger.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-memcached</artifactId>
   <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and ended up doing more or less what Sergey described in his answer. If anyone else is looking for an answer to this problem you can give this a try https://github.com/mihaicostin/hibernate-l2-memcached